# How to use sized traits in structs?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the AES crate, which offers three algorithms: AES128, AES192 and AES256. I'm trying to create a struct that can create the correct algorithm by detecting the key size, and save it to later use.

I see they all implement the BlockEncrypt (I only need encryption) trait, but when I try to make a field in the struct with this type, even when supplying the size, i get an "the trait `BlockEncrypt` cannot be made into an object. the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized` " error.

```
pub struct MyStruct<'a, T: Sized> {
       ciph: Box< dyn BlockEncrypt<BlockSize = T>>,
}
```

Comment: You can't use dynamic dispatch with traits that have `Sized` as a supertrait. You'll have to use a newtype/enum and do the dynamic dispatch manually, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on how to approach it, or perhaps a link to an implementation of something similar? I'm a beginner and not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @cdhowie mentioned, you can't create a trait object from a trait with a `Sized` bound. Instead, you can create an enum:

```rust
enum MyAlgorithm {
    AES128(AES128),
    AES192(AES192),
    AES256(AES256),
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended up doing. It still looks odd to have a match where all 3 arms do the same thing though. Is that how its supposed to be?

Comment: Yes. Even though the match arms look the same, they operate on different types, so it can't be helped.

Comment: @RaniSharim You can alleviate the repetition somewhat using macros.

Comment: @RaniSharim you could use the [enum_dispatch](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/) crate to automatically generate trait methods on the enum that delegate to the variants

Answer (score 5):

Traits that have `Sized` as a supertype aren't "object safe" which means dynamic dispatch using `dyn` isn't possible on these kinds of traits.

You can accomplish this *relatively* tersely by using an enum for each possible type you want to handle, combined with a macro that will neatly generate all the `match` arms required to dynamically dispatch on each enum possibility.

To make things simple for the sake of this explanation, I'm going to define a new trait (with the `Sized` supertype) so that this answer doesn't depend on a particular crate:

```
trait SampleTrait: Sized {
    fn method_a(&self, foo: &str);
    fn method_b(&self, foo: i32, bar: String) -> String;
}
```

Now we need at least two implementations of this trait to demonstrate the solution:

```
struct ImplA;
struct ImplB;

impl SampleTrait for ImplA {
    fn method_a(&self, foo: &str) {
        println!("<ImplA as SampleTrait>::method_a(): {:?}", foo);
    }
    
    fn method_b(&self, foo: i32, bar: String) -> String {
        println!("<ImplA as SampleTrait>::method_b(): {:?} {:?}", foo, bar);
        format!("from ImplA: {}", bar)
    }
}

impl SampleTrait for ImplB {
    fn method_a(&self, foo: &str) {
        println!("<ImplB as SampleTrait>::method_a(): {:?}", foo);
    }
    
    fn method_b(&self, foo: i32, bar: String) -> String {
        println!("<ImplB as SampleTrait>::method_b(): {:?} {:?}", foo, bar);
        format!("from ImplB: {}", bar)
    }
}
```

The enum just needs to least each possible type that you need to handle:

```
enum DynSampleTrait {
    ImplA(ImplA),
    ImplB(ImplB),
}
```

Now to dispatch on this, you'd have to do something like:

```
match value {
    DynSampleTrait::ImplA(v) => v.method_a("something"),
    DynSampleTrait::ImplB(v) => v.method_a("something"),
}
```

To get around having to repeat ourselves, let's declare a macro that will generate the whole `match` for us:

```
macro_rules! dyn_sample_trait_call {
    (($m:expr) $v:ident => $code:block) => {
        match $m {
            DynSampleTrait::ImplA($v) => $code,
            DynSampleTrait::ImplB($v) => $code,
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use the macro like so:

```
dyn_sample_trait_call!((value) v => { v.method_a("something") })
```

`value` goes in the match expression, and `v` is the identifier that unwraps the inner value held by the enum possibility.  These are separate so that you can match over a reference, should you not want to consume an owned `DynSampleTrait`:

```
dyn_sample_trait_call!((&value) v => { v.method_a("something") })
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c4e2817816dc161b2bbda987937d305))